# Как правильно организовать крон скрипт (задачу)?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

**Суть задачи:** Есть база данных, в ней таблица со статусами задач. Необходимо по прохождению 70 дней менять статус.

Я сделал два поля у таблицы : `CREATE_DATE` и `UPDATE_DATE`. При создании задачи, устанавливается одинаковая дата в оба поля. Как только значение поля
 `UPDATE_DATE` становятся равным 70 дней с момента создания я обновляю дату и перевожу в другое состояние.

**Как реализовано сейчас:** скрипт выполняющийся кроном вытаскивает все задачи нужного состояния и проверяет у каждой задачи значение поля `UPDATE_DATE`.

**Проблема:** Указанная выше реализация не верная, так как если задач будет пару миллионов сервак просто повиснет.

**Вопрос:** Я хочу запускать крон скрипт каждые 10 минут, который будет вытаскивать по 10 записей. А каждый следующий запуск скрипт не пробегался по всей бд, а продолжал с работу с той позиции на которой остановился. Соответственно когда он пробежался по всей бд, начать опять с начала.

*Принимается критика, если данный подход в принципе не возможен или не верен.*

Comment: CRON фтопку. У MySQL есть собственный встроенный планировщик aka Event Sheduler. [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html), [CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html).

Comment: A вообще - зачем менять-то? `SELECT ... , CASE WHEN status_date < current_date - INTERVAL 70 DAY THEN 'altered status' ELSE status END AS status, ...`, и всё.

Comment: @Akina Да, но мне надо ещё и уведомлять об изменении по почте. И писать логи.

Comment: Из процедуры, запускаемой по EVENT, можно писать хоть логи в таблицу логов, хоть что... А на почту уже пусть отправляет CRON, вытаскивая сведения для отправки из таблицы логов, скажем, раз в сутки. Впрочем, процедура в EVENT запросто может выгружать нужные для отправки данные в файл (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE), так что скрипту или программе из крона не потребуется дёргать MySQL.

Comment: @Akina так если нужно работать с базой + ещё работа с почтой и тп., разве не легче CRON использовать? Мне кажется, что если нужна только работа с базой, то лучше Event. Может ошибаюсь конечно......

Comment: event работает с БД. Скажем, раз в минуту выгружает ID тухлыx записей в таблицу логов, затем апдейтит их статус. Второй event раз в сутки выгружает список ID из таблицы логов (и, если надо, доп. данные по ним из таблицы задач) в файл на диске, затем помечает их как выгруженные. А cron раз в сутки берёт этот файл с диска и отправляет на почту. В результате каждый занят своим делом и в чужую вотчину не лезет.

Comment: А кто меняет поле update_date, этот самый скрипт или кто то другой ? Это я к тому может скрипту прицельно брать нужные задачи из БД. А не все 2 миллиона с нужным статусом

Comment: @Mike Тот же самый. Нужен определённый тип задач.

Comment: Не понимаю логику изменения update_date. Но что то мне подсказывает, что его надо менять как можно реже. По каким критериям скрипт сейчас понимает, что надо изменить update_date ? Что происходит с задачей после того, как 70 дней прошло, скрипт это отработал, выслал почту и т.п. он как то помечает записи, что бы с ними дальше уже не производить действий ?

Comment: @Mike Я бы сказал, что проблема то не в обновлении данного поля, а проблема с проходится по всей базе с целью найти и проанализировать статусы с определённым типом. Скрипт берёт значение этого поля, прибавляет к нему 70 дней и сравнивает с текущей, если равны то значит прошло 70 дней и перезаписываем дату (`UPDATE_DATE`) и меняет тип задачи.(+почта). Никак не помечает и хотелось бы этого не делать. Суть всех этих манипуляций привести эту задачу в тип который конечный. Например, **задача выполнена**.

Comment: @Mike Суть поля `UPDATE_DATE` заключается в том, что есть разные типы задач, с разным интервалом времени проверки.

Comment: А если он будет брать задачи по условию `where type='нужный тип' and date_create <= now()-interval 70 day`, он же уже найдет далеко не 2 миллиона, а собственно все, которые пора обновлять. Если предположить, что скрипт работает всегда и скажем не может быть просроченных более чем на неделю задач с нужными типами, то можно еще добавить условие `date_create > now()-interval 80 day` и тогда он уже заведомо поднимет из таблицы только задачи дней за 10, которых явно не 2 млн. При наличии индекса по полю date_create это очень быстро.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90079/discussion-between-doox911-and-mike).